# How to catch response from web when redirecting back to the app? [React Native, Deep Linking]

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I use React Native's library for deep linking called `Linking`. For now, I just open URL which redirects to the web where the user has to log in to a certain website. After the user logs in it redirects him back to the app. 
Now, the problem is that I have to know if the user did log in or not (just pressed back button). Is it possible to catch response somehow? 
I'd need to catch id of app.nameoftheapp://?ID=id which is how web redirects back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write an if statement so it will let the user go back only if he/she has logged in.

Comment: Hm, the problem appears when user clicks the back button on the device. Then the redirect from the web doesn't happen. Just the redirect in the device which is not connected to the app.nameoftheapp://?ID=id.